# MySQL stored procedure for deduplicating records not working as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to "deduplicate" records with overlapping time periods in my database.

Example of the data in my table:

[image]

First of all I group records by CODE, TYPE and VALID, meaning I am searching for overlapping time periods only for records where those values match.

In the picture above there would be 3 overlapping records with IDs 100, 101 and 102.

What I would like to do is to add values into column CPNEW to "deduplicate" those records, I would like to add something like "I" to "I&(x)" where x is the amount of overlapping records, so for IDs 100 to 102 it would be I, I1, I2 with descending order based on DATEVALIDTO, something like this:

[image]

Now, I wrote a simple select query which does exactly what I want, it looks like this:

```
UPDATE clist2 as con2fin 
JOIN( 
SELECT con.*, 
(CASE WHEN con.VALID = "NOT_VALID" THEN 
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) > 6, 
CONCAT("I","NOK"), 
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) = 1, "I", 
CONCAT("I", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC)-1))) 
ELSE 
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) > 10, 
CONCAT("A","NOK"), IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) = 1, "A", 
CONCAT("A", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC)-1))) END) as cp_new 
FROM clist2 as con 
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM database_1.clist2 WHERE ID = 101) as fin 
on fin.CODE = con.CODE AND fin.VALID = con.VALID AND fin.TYPE = con.TYPE 
AND 
( 
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM <= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO <= con.DATEVALIDTO) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDFROM >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO <= con.DATEVALIDTO) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDFROM >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDFROM <= con.DATEVALIDTO AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDTO) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDFROM <= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDTO) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDTO = con.DATEVALIDTO) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDTO = con.DATEVALIDFROM) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDFROM = con.DATEVALIDFROM) 
OR (fin.DATEVALIDFROM = con.DATEVALIDTO) 
)) as con2beforefin 
on con2beforefin.ID = con2fin.ID 
SET con2fin.CPNEW = con2beforefin.cp_new ;
```

This is set to deduplicate all records which overlap with record with ID 101.

Unfortunately i have a lot of records in this table and I need to create query, which would do this for every record in the table, meaning:

1. Find all records which overlap with first record
2. Deduplicate found records
3. Jump to next record
4. If this record was already "deduplicated" skip this record, otherwise do step 2.
5. Jump to next records
6. If this record was already "deduplicated" skip this record, otherwise do step 2.
   etc.

I basically need to loop this logic.

So it would look like this:

[image]

**Question**

So I thought I could use a stored procedure with cursor and loop for this, so I wrote this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN

-- Variables
        DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_ID varchar(10000) DEFAULT "";

-- Cursor to get ID
        DECLARE curID 
        CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT ID FROM clist2;

-- NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

-- OPEN cursor 
    OPEN curID;

-- START LOOP
    getID: LOOP

-- FETCH Cursor value into variable
        FETCH curID INTO v_ID;

-- CHECK IF NOT FOUND handler = 1
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getID;
        ELSE

-- LOGIC PART OF SP

-- PART 1, IF CPNEW IS BLANK DO THIS

if ((SELECT CPNEW FROM clist2 WHERE ID = @v_ID) is null) then 

UPDATE clist2 as con2fin
JOIN(
SELECT con.*, 
(CASE
WHEN con.VALID = "NOT_VALID"
THEN
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) > 6,
CONCAT("I","NOK"),
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) = 1,
"I", CONCAT("I", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC)-1)))
ELSE
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) > 10,
CONCAT("A","NOK"),
IF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC) = 1,
"A", CONCAT("A", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY con.CODE, con.TYPE, con.VALID ORDER BY con.DATEVALIDTO DESC)-1)))
END) as cp_new FROM clist2 as con
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM database_1.clist2
WHERE ID = @v_ID) as fin
on fin.CODE = con.CODE AND fin.VALID = con.VALID AND fin.TYPE = con.TYPE
AND (
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM <= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO <= con.DATEVALIDTO)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO <= con.DATEVALIDTO)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM >= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDFROM <= con.DATEVALIDTO AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDTO)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM <= con.DATEVALIDFROM AND fin.DATEVALIDTO >= con.DATEVALIDTO)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDTO = con.DATEVALIDTO)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDTO = con.DATEVALIDFROM)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM = con.DATEVALIDFROM)
OR
(fin.DATEVALIDFROM = con.DATEVALIDTO)
)) as con2beforefin on con2beforefin.ID = con2fin.ID
SET con2fin.CPNEW = con2beforefin.cp_new
;

-- PART 2, if CPNEW IS NOT BLANK DO THIS

else 
        UPDATE clist2 SET CPNEW = CPNEW
        WHERE ID = @v_ID;

-- END OF THE SP

    end if;
    END IF;
END LOOP getID;
CLOSE curID;
SET @finished = 0;
end
```

Unfortunately this stored procedure yields no result.

What do i have wrong, what to change to make it work?

Thank you very much

Comment: Data should be posted as text, so that if somebody wants to help has no bother wuth typing his own data or even better make qa dbfiddle example. Second your code is unreadable, not because it is big , its because there is no structure. so i gave up after the first bug (SELECT CPNEW FROM clist2 WHERE ID = v_ID)  you want to use the variable in which your cursor put your number and not a session variable that isn't declared

Comment: You are absolutely right, i will edit my post. Regarding my question, you were also right, i was so overthinking that i did not use declared variable. I changed that and the code seems to be working, i will do some testing and post results and hopefully also an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nbk Thanks again, all i had to do was to delete "@", now it works like charm, i tested it and it works.

If you could post your answer i would flag it as asnwer.